# Jackson JSON Property Map unpack

Tags: java, json, kotlin

I have a class in java

```java
public class A {
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> dateToAmountMap;
}
```

which gets through a
`ResponseEntity<A>`
to a kotlin receiver that does something in this direction

```kotlin
class Receiver {
    ... // check if valid Serialization {}
    val json = input.decodeJsonElement().jsonObject
    ... // check if json.values.any is not null

    // TODO: this is the part i dont know how to unpack the map from 
    // JSON to then 1) check if it is not null and then 2) use it:
    // do i try to manipulate it as ?.jsonArray or ?.jsonObject  ?
    val dateToAmountMap = json["dateToAmountMap"]?.jsonArray
}
```

I was trying to do something in this direction

```kotlin
dateToAmountMap.map { (key, value) -> LocalDate.parse(key) to value as BigDecimal }
```

but it doesnt work if i grab `.?jsonArray`. Any kind of guideline for me to research / read documentation is very welcome, since I am completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin you can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` for serialising and deserialising Json objects.

In order to serialise the an object you can use:
ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(theObject)

In order to deserialise the an object you can use:
ObjectMapper().readValue(content, YourClassDto::class.java)

Comment: thank you! i will try this out!